# Why would my John Deere 915b zero turn mower quit mid mow and now won’t restart?

Tags: lawn-mower

Mower is approximately 4-5 years old. I was mowing with the blade engage. The mower suddenly stopped and would not restart. It makes a slight hum when I turn the key but there is no sound from the engine. I left it alone for an hour in case it was overheated. Still the same results.

Comment: Quiet hum like from an electrical relay, or loud hum like the starter motor is spinning but not engaging?

Comment: You should open the user's/maintence manual to find the potential problems on startup and how to troubleshoot.

Comment: If it still has the original battery, it will at least need a new one.  Oil is checked/changed regularly and other maintenance items done as needed?

Comment: Check the safety circuits: it may have a switch that stops the engine if the operator rises from the seat while the blades are engaged (and this switch or wiring could have failed). There also can be safeties that prevent starting the engine if various controls are left in the wrong position.

Comment: Did it seem to be running normally when it stopped?  Any unusual sounds?  As @Jack mentioned, check the oil level.  If the oil level is extremely low (or no oil), there's a good chance your motor has seized, and is probably ruined.

Comment: Low oil shut off maybe

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: Make sure that the blade engaging switch is turned off.